# How can I intercept and modify HTTP requests?

Tags: appsec, tools, penetration-test, http

Are there any free tools available that let me intercept and modify HTTP requests for testing?

I am looking for tools which allow me to send custom HTTP headers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I personally am partial to Fiddler, a free [download](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) from MS.
There are many other decent interactive http proxies, but that one serves me the best.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned above, there are a number of HTTP proxies that allow intercepting and modifying requests and responses.

Here is a list of the ones I know about:

- WebScarab (disclaimer: I wrote it)
- Paros
- Burp
- ZAP (Z Attack Proxy - an updated version of Paros)
- Fiddler/Fiddler2
- Achilles
- HTTPush
- Exodus (disclaimer: I wrote it, and it is really old)

If you wish to write your own intercepting proxy, you might like to take a look at OWASP Proxy, a Java library that implements all the necessary HTTP protocol functionality so you don't have to.

Answer (score 10):

A while ago I used the [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/) Firefox Add-on and found it to be quite effective. 
It has some good features like being able to choose what requests you wish to tamper with and also has some predefined exploits that you can use to populate field values with.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Burp now rocks. Portswigger has made some excellent developments in the last 2 years. From the [website](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html), Burp can:

- Intercept and modify all HTTP/S
  traffic passing in both directions.
- Easily analyze all kinds of content,
  with automatic colorizing of request
  and response syntax, rendering of web
  content, and parsing of serialization
  schemes like AMF.
- Apply fine-grained rules to determine
  which requests and responses are
  intercepted for manual testing.
- View all traffic in the detailed
  proxy history, with advanced filters
  and search functions.
- Send interesting items to other Burp
  Suite tools with a single click.
- Save all of your work, and resume
  working later.
- Quickly search and highlight
  interesting content within HTTP
  messages.
- Work with custom SSL certificates and
  non-proxy-aware clients.
- Define rules to automatically modify
  requests and responses without manual
  intervention.

And I would definitely recommend the entire burp suite!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Firefox add-on [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) so you can view and replay them.

Answer (score 3):

Paros and Burp are the 2 most common open-source options.  There is a commercial version of Burp available as well.  They are both written in Java.

Answer (score 3):

The [Fiddler HTTP debugging](http://www.fiddler2.com) proxy has been around for years and is actively maintained.  It allows for interception and modification of traffic, crafting custom requests, replaying requests, and is fully scriptable and extendable.  It's a Windows-only tool.

It also has [extensions](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/extensions.asp) for passive and active security testing.  Disclaimer - I co-authored those.

Comment: Ah thanks for the props, feature requests, bugs, and new ideas for security checks are always welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Paros Proxy and Burp both function as proxies, allowing you to intercept and modify HTTP requests and responses.

Answer (score 2):

Owasp has released a tool called [Web Scarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project)

Answer (score 1):

I've used Paros, webscarab and burp extensively and burp wins hands down. There is a free version, but the full version is also very good value at £150/year.

Answer (score 0):

An rare occasions, I've had to use wfetch (another free [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=B134A806-D50E-4664-8348-DA5C17129210&displaylang=en) from MS), to handle raw bytage over the HTTP stream. The specific problem being that almost all other tools, especially proxies and browser plugins, necessarily URL-encode any non-printable characters... and sometimes, you just really want to send that chr(9)....

Comment: Burp Suite will let you turn off the auto-encoding of those metacharacters

Comment: @atdre, really? You can send e.g. raw NULL bytes? Hadn't seen that... Might go back to Burp sometime, it's been a while... Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

I like MITM Proxy: http://mitmproxy.org/

(Careful, there's another project with the same name.)

It has a really lean, interfaces (looks like ncurses), if you like that sort of thing. It has the same capture/view/edit/replay capabilities as many others, but it's very keyboard-friendly. It can also proxy SSL connections!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add (as it seems to have been missed so far) that if you're using Firefox, there's a collection called "Samurai Web Testing Framework" created by Raul Siles that comes with all cool webapp-sec related plugins included in the collection - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections/rsiles/samurai/.