# Intercepting HTTP requests from a Java Application

Tags: http, http-proxy, appsec

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way of capturing and modifying the requests sent out by a Java application over HTTP. I can see them in Wireshark, but I also want to be able to modify them in transit (modify destination/POST data).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a Http Proxy.

In this related question you will find a list of proposed http proxies [How can I intercept and modify HTTP requests?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/223/how-can-i-intercept-and-modify-http-requests?rq=1)